# Compile Latex code using Swift

Tags: swift, terminal, xelatex

I wanted to compile a `.tex` file using Swift. I have the following code:

```
class FileManager {
    class func compileLatex(#file: String) {
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/texbin/latexmk"
        task.currentDirectoryPath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String).stringByAppendingString("/roster")
        task.arguments = ["-xelatex", file]
        task.launch()
    }
}
```

However, when calling `FileManager.compileLatex(file: "latex.tex")` I get the error 'launch path not accessible'. So apparently, the launch path is wrong, yet I don't know how to find out which it really is? How can I find out or is there a general path? Thanks for any help

EDIT:

updated code and getting this error:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 10 January 2015, version: 4.42.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex  -recorder  "Praktikumsbericht.tex"'
------------
sh: xelatex: command not found
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'Praktikumsbericht.log'
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'Praktikumsbericht.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX failed to generate the expected log file 'Praktikumsbericht.log'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `launchPath` must be set to the path of the executable,
for example

```
task.launchPath = "/usr/texbin/latexmk"
```

The `currentDirectoryPath` can optionally be set to execute the
task in a specified directory. The "Documents" directory 
is usually determined like this:

```
task.currentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
```

Finally, the `arguments` are the command line arguments for
the executable, for example

```
task.arguments = ["-xelatex", file]
```

*Alternatively,* you can start the executable using the shell,
something like

```
task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
task.currentDirectoryPath = ...
task.arguments = ["-c", "latexmk -xelatex \"\(file)\""]
```

The advantage is that the shell uses the PATH environment variable to
locate the executable. One disadvantage is that quoting the arguments
correctly is more difficult.

*Update:* It seems that "/usr/texbin" must be in the PATH for the
LaTeX process. This can be done as follows:

```
// Get current environment:
var env = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment
// Get PATH:
var path = env["PATH"] as String
// Prepend "/usr/texbin":
path = "/usr/texbin:" + path
// Put back to environment:
env["PATH"] = path
// And use this as environment for the task:
task.environment = env
```

Comment: Can I simply "add" a folder to the current directory path like `task.currentDirectoryPath = task.currentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingString("/folder")`?

Comment: @OliverBorchert: currentDirectoryPath is not the *search path*. It corresponds to the "current working directory" in the Terminal. Also NSTask does not use the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @OliverBorchert: Alternatively, you can use the shell to execute the command (I have to lookup the exact parameters, but that must have been answered somewhere). Then the shell will search the latexmk program in the search PATH. The downside is that quoting the arguments correctly is more difficult.

Comment: ok, thanks first it works now, however when executing the task I get an error whereas when executing directly in terminal it works. I will add the error to my question

Comment: Trying to use your second approach, I get the error `/bin/sh: latexmk: command not found`

Comment: @OliverBorchert: Then the problem is that "/usr/texbin" is not in the search path of your process. I think you can set it using `task.environment`. I don't have the time right now to find the exact syntax but will update the answer later if I find it.

Comment: @OliverBorchert: I have added some code, perhaps that helps. – I do not have TeX installed currently, so I cannot completely test it myself.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now :D hope I could give you more than one upvote... :D